# Is it safe to push to the remote a branch created from git clone --single-branch?

Tags: git, gitlab

One git local repository is cloned in one place with --single-branch option, because we know in this context, we will only work on a single branch, and need to save space.
Is it safe to push back modifs from this clone to the original remote repository?

I pushed a new local branch from it with a few commits to the original remote, and it took quite a while, as if it was pushing a whole branch history. Now in Gitlab, the commit graph seems to show the histories are properly merged.
The branch graph coloring seems strange, as if my original cloned branch was only branched from the new pushed branch (i only see the original branch line on the commits done after my new branch was branched, the comits done before that are colored  with the new branch color). But maybe that's just because the new branch has the most recent commit
Also, it looks like gitlab says the storage for the project somewhat doubled from what is used to be, as if it stored twice the history or something. But i couldn't certify it since i did not look at the size recently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, certainly.

You have cloned a single branch of your interest from the repository, so you have that starting point in place (with its entire commits available). Now if you create a new branch from it, that branch will have the history from the sourced branch until the commit you have branched out, and then onwards any more commits you push to it. The commit history of interest for this work stays in place and so shouldn't clash with any remote changes.

If the size of the repo is doubling out by this, chances are you just had that single branch in the repo before or the branch you created this new branch from was significantly bigger than any more additional branches present, so now having its history until branching point will lead to this sudden rise in your repository storage.